# How to stop JavaScript removing the 0 from a number after the decimal point?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, parsefloat

I am using JQuery to do some calculations on some items that a user selects. One of the items which is priced at £13.95, when 2 are selected gives £27.90. However, the result is always displayed as £27.9, the sum removes the last 0.

How can I stop the Javascript doing this? Here is the code I am using - `#pucMoH` contains 13.95 as a string, which is then converted to a float:

```
var MoHCost = parseFloat($('#pucMoH').text()).toFixed(2);
var SelectedVal = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
var SelectedSum = MoHCost * SelectedValInt;
```

Comment: Note that this is nothing to do with jQuery, but instead native JS.

Comment: I've amended the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your question; `toFixed(2)`:

```
var MoHCost = parseFloat($('#pucMoH').text()).toFixed(2);
var SelectedVal = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
var SelectedSum = (MoHCost * SelectedValInt).toFixed(2);
```